# Using gdb to inspect "non-current" thread on eCos mips target

Tags: gdb, mips, ecos

I have a MIPS target running eCos, which uses several thread. For debugging I'm using gdb 7.5 and a JTAG probe.

How can I from GDB inspect and back trace a non-current thread. I do have the base thread address, and the program counter from the alternative thread (I can properly find other information if I need it).

As gdb is not aware of eCos, commands such as "info threads" does not work. So I will most likely have to manual which the thread context in gdb...

Answer (score 0):

We use the [Code Confidence tools](http://www.codeconfidence.com/ecos-tools.shtml) for Eclipse which allows eCos thread-aware debugging through JTAG. It is not free but it works very well, is up kept to date with new Eclipse versions and the support that John Dallaway offers is very good. I highly recommend it if you are doing any serious eCos development.